# how to manipulate hightcharts data in jquery?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to manipulate hightcharts data to display pie chart by doing as:

```
<div style="display: none" id="main-data">
    <span data-name="Firefox" data-value="45"></span>
    <span data-name="IE" data-value="26.8"></span>
</div>

function getPieData() {
var dataArr = [];
$('#main-data span').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    dataArr.push(name);
    dataArr.push(value);
});

return dataArr;
}

var dataArr = [['Firefox',45.0],['IE',26.8]];
var dataArr1 = getPieData();
```

If I use dataArr, the chart display fine. But if I use dataArr1, it just display 1 single vertical line. I have tried to print out both of the dataArr and see that they both format exactly. How can I fix my dataArr1 to display a pie chart as dataArr does?

Answer (score 0):

The array you create with your function (`dataArr1`) is one-dimensional, while the one that you manually instantiated (`dataArr`) is two-dimensional. It has to be two-dimensional to contain name-value pairs.

At the end of your example your arrays contain the following:

```
dataArr = [['Firefox', 45.0], ['IE', 26.8]];
dataArr1 = ['Firefox', 45, 'IE', 26.8];
```

You need to push arrays into your array, inside your `getPieData()` function. For example like this:

```
function getPieData() {
    var dataArr = [];
    $('#main-data span').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).data("name");
        var value = $(this).data("value");
        dataArr.push([name, value]);
    });

    return dataArr;
}
```